# Why does emacs not load full configuration until `load-file` is called?

Tags: init-file, load

tl;dr
I have the following snippet in config file:

```lisp
  (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
  (setq-default tab-width 4)
  (setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
```

It does not load until I load the init file using `load-file` command. Why it happens and how to fix it?

Summary:

I have my emacs config in a file [config.org](https://github.com/chhajedji/.emacs.d/blob/master/config.org) and I am loading it from [init.el](https://github.com/chhajedji/.emacs.d/blob/master/init.el#L12) through `(org-babel-load-file "~/.emacs.d/config.org")` command. I have the above snippet to configure tab in the config.org file. When opening fresh emacs, this configuration does not take effect until I call `org-babel-load-file`. As soon as I call this function, without changing anything tab length automatically becomes to the set value. I also placed the same snippet at the end of my init.el file, but still tab length did not get set to 4. As soon as I reload the init.el file using `load-file`, tab length becomes the set value.

Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: Naturally Emacs *does* load the full configuration at init time (unless you have errors in your config, but then you would be seeing an error message, and could use `emacs --debug-init` to produce a backtrace).  I suspect your question is actually "why does a thing I set at init time not have the effect I expected in some buffer I'm dealing with later" and that's a very different question.  The setting may be getting clobbered, or you may not have been setting it in an appropriate way in the first place.

Comment: Down-voted due to the lack of follow-up, to prevent the Community bot from bumping the question again.  The question seems like it was prompted by other points of confusion, and is unlikely to be useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC your question is about `tab-width`.

This variable is automatically buffer-local (as indicated by `C-h v tab-width`), meaning that whenever it is set in a buffer it acquires a buffer-local value.

Buffers which do *not* set `tab-width` will see the default value, but if `tab-width` is set at all, then it is disconnected from the default value of that variable, in which case your `setq-default` is irrelevant as far as that buffer is concerned.

What does <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `tab-width` tell you in the buffer in question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your explanation about buffer-local value explains a lot. However, I am not observing the expected behavior. I have the above snippet in my init file, and when I am in a C file, I can see the default indentation to be 2 spaces. When I do `C-h`- `v`- `tab-width`, then I see a line saying: "_Its value is 4. Original value was 8_". I was expecting its value to be 2 and not 4. Can you please explain this?

Comment: The `tab-width` variable just tells Emacs how to render tab characters (ascii 9).  If it tells you that the value is 4, then it will be displaying each tab character with a *maximum* width equivalent to 4 spaces (whatever is necessary to reach the next tab stop column / multiple of tab-width).  If the *code* does not use tabs for indentation (i.e. if it is 2 space characters for each indent, rather than 1 tab character) then `tab-width` isn't relevant at all.